# What is the default path to the MIDL Compiler in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, build, visual-studio-2013

As the question states, what is the default path to the [MIDL Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Visual Studio 2013 (or previous versions) for those who want to manually run it from the command line to build IDL files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the Platform Toolset you have selected for a project.  The default one (v120) takes you to c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\bin\x86\midl.exe.  If you target XP (v120_xp) then you get c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\bin\midl.exe

You normally don't care and use the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: You could simple open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and type "where midl"

Answer (score 2):

Our sources seem to expect it in Program\ Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0/bin/MIDL.exe so in the SDK rather than in VS.  I suspect it may have been removed from the win8 sdk though when they removed the compiler.  We have not yet ported to that SDK.

Comment: I have it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin...but this seems iffy to put on a build script. Note the difference in v7.0 for you and v7.0A for me. I need something more generic than this for my team to use as a reliable build script!

Comment: That's the VS2010 path.  If you don't have the A version then you installed the Windows SDK separately.